# scrapy list of requests delayed

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to scrape a list of web pages 10 times at 5 minute intervals.
This is to collect URLs for later scraping.  Another way to look at it is

```
url_list = []
for i in 1:10 {
   url_list += scrape request
   url_list += scrape request
   url_list += scrape request
   sleep 5 min
}
for site in url_list
    scrape site
```

How can I add a delay between the sets, but no delay between the scraping requests?

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Clarified description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` project settings or `download_delay` spider class attribute with a number of desired delay in seconds.

[Official docs on download_delay](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay)